# ¿Cómo solucionar el error ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname de Python?

Tags: python, windows, pip

Tenía instalados Python 3.11 y Python 3.8, pero luego de desinstalarlos y volver a instalar el Python 3.8, cuando intento utilizar pip install, me muestra el error: ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname. Ya sea que descargue los paquetes de Pypi o por cualquier otra vía, sigue dando el mismo error. ¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta el comando

```
pip install nombre_modulo --proxy http://192.168.100.30:8088
```

En Windows, pero antes de eso, asegúrate de que no haya ningún proxy seleccionado.

Puedes hacerlo yendo a `Internet Explorer >> Settings >> Internet Options >> Connections >> Lan Settings` y desmarcando las tres casillas de verificación.

La otra probabilidad es que tengas el vpn encendido trata de apagarlo y vuelve a usa `pip`.

Ña ultima opción que veo factible es que vayas a `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local` y borres la carpeta `pip` y vuelvas a instalar todo si la carpeta `Appdata` no esta ve a la configuración de las carpeta y dale en Mostrar carpetas ocultas

**Atención! la ruta varia depende de la versión de python que tengas en el ordenador**